# Why can't i choose the option 'Allow projects within this group to use Git LFS' in group's setting of gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

1. [The panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaIMT.png).I want to open the assess of lfs in my group,the picture above.
2. But when i click it and try to save change, it always be the state of unselected.I need help everybody, thanks!
3. I except it can be selected, but i can't select the option，although i try my best, so i need help!